# How to get the exact Font out of Fontfamily?

Tags: c#, fonts, picturebox, font-family

I want to create a Picturebox that adapts its shape to a string of a certain Font. I need this so that I can later create texts and lay it over an AxWindowsMediaPlayer control.

Therefore I created the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace myProject
{
    class ShapedPictureBoxes : PictureBox
    {
        public ShapedPictureBoxes()
        {
            this.Paint += this.shapedPaint;
        }

    void shapedPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath graphicsPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();


Font font = new Font("Arial", 14f);
float emSize = e.Graphics.DpiY*font.Size/72;
        graphicsPath.AddString(text, new FontFamily("Arial"), (int)System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, emSize, new Point(0,0), new StringFormat());

        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Red, new Point(0, 0));

        this.Region = new Region(graphicsPath);
    }

    public string text = "Here comes the sun, doo da doo do";
}

}
```

The problem now is, that the "Graphics.DrawString" does not match the graphicspath.AddString, probably because FontFamily isn't the same as Font. How can I match them?

So: How can I convert Fontfamily to Font or viceversa?

This is how it looks like:

[image: the result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for the fact that the `Font` size is specified in units of points, but the `AddString()` size is specified in device units.

You can convert the units as follows:

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", 14f, FontStyle.Bold);
float emSize = e.Graphics.DpiY * font.Size / 72; // Here's the conversion.
graphicsPath.AddString(text, new FontFamily("Arial"), (int)System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, emSize, new Point(0, 0), new StringFormat());
```

Note that I'm passing the calculated `emSize` to `AddString()` instead of passing `14f`.

Comment: it looks better now: I adapted the question with your partial solution and added a picture...

Comment: @Salocin I just noticed that your `AddString()` is using Bold, but your font isn't. I've updated my example so the Font uses Bold. What happens now if you do the same?

Comment: oh, that was a mistake that was just in the question.. the screenshot leads from Fontstyle.Regular... the problem stays the same... it looks as if the two texts shift away from each other the longer the text is..

Comment: @Salocin I expect that's because they are using slightly different drawing functions. In particular, `DrawText()` can use [ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartypeinfo.mspx), but `AddString()` never does.

Comment: oh.. so you mean there is no solution to the problem?

Comment: @Salocin I'm afraid not. (I'm pretty sure it's ClearType differences.)